# awk print date formats for all letters - lower and upper cases

Tags: bash, awk

I'm working on a awk one-liner to get the date command output for all possible characters ( upper and lower case) like below

```
a Tue | A Tuesday
b Apr | B April
c Tue Apr 14 17:33:37 2020 | C 20
d 14 | D 04/14/20
. . . .
. . . . 
z +0530 | Z IST
```

The below command seems to be syntactically correct, but awk is throwing error.

```
seq 0 25 | awk ' { d="date \"+" printf("%c",$0+97) " %" printf("%c",$0+97) "\""; d | getline ; print } '
```

`` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)' ``

what is wrong with my attempt. Any other awk solution is also welcome.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus, my first code block is the desired output.  I'm trying to simulate ````date "+a %a | A %A"```` for all alphabets

Comment: Everywhere you use `printf`, ITYM `sprintf`. Having said that, if you're getting the syntax error you say you are (`-bash: syntax error...`) then something is wrong earlier in the bash script you're calling awk from since that's a bash syntax error, not an awk one. Please post a complete but minimal bash script that demonstrates the problem since we can't debug what we can't see. But first - copy/paste your bash script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and it'll probably just tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @EdMorton.. yes you are right.. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have this:

```
awk -v q='"' 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<=25;i++){
    ch=sprintf("%c",i+97)
    d="date +%s%s %%%s%s " 
    sprintf(d, q,ch,ch,q)|getline v;
    sprintf(d,q,toupper(ch),toupper(ch),q)|getline v2;
    print v "|" v2
    close(d)
}}'
```

### Note

- you don't need to feed awk by `seq 0 25`, you can use the `BEGIN` block
- `printf` does output, if you want the result, use `sprintf()`
- you should `close` the command after execution
- you didn't implement the "uppercase" part

### Output:

```
a Tue|A Tuesday
b Apr|B April
c Tue 14 Apr 2020 03:02:33 PM CEST|C 20
d 14|D 04/14/20
e 14|E %E
f %f|F 2020-04-14
g 20|G 2020
h Apr|H 15
i %i|I 03
j 105|J %J
k 15|K %K
l  3|L %L
m 04|M 02
n |N 396667929
o %o|O %O
p PM|P pm
q 2|Q %Q
r 03:02:33 PM|R 15:02
s 1586869353|S 33
t   |T 15:02:33
u 2|U 15
v %v|V 16
w 2|W 15
x 04/14/2020|X 03:02:33 PM
y 20|Y 2020
z +0200|Z CEST
```

Comment: You also got a not-so-best in the use of getline. `sprintf(d, q,ch,ch,q)|getline v` should actually be `cmd=sprintf(d, q,ch,ch,q); v=( (cmd |getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" ); close(cmd)`. Ditto for the other call to it too of course. The current code would silently corrupt the output if `date |getline` failed and the `close(d)` is doing nothing as the string contained in `d` isn't the string used to open the pipe. See awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to call it if you're ever considering using `getline.`

Answer (score 3):

bash can do this:

```sh
for c in {a..z}; do date "+$c %$c | ${c^} %${c^}"; done
```

Comment: thanks for the bash solution. I was looking for portable one and so used awk.

Comment: If you're concerned about portability, be aware that not all `date` (and `strftime`) implementations are the same. For example BSD `date +%v` is "14-Apr-2020" and GNU `date +%N`

Comment: Use 2 separate brace expansions: `{a..z} {A..Z}` -- bash [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) is pretty rudimentary.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(without ASCII numbers using trick).

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
BEGIN{
  num=split("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z",alphabets,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    print "date " s1 "+"alphabets[i] " %"alphabets[i] " | " toupper(alphabets[i]) " %"toupper(alphabets[i]) s1
  }
}
' | bash
```

***Logical explanation:***

- Starting `awk` program and mentioning variable s1 with value `"`.
- Everything we re doing is in `BEGIN` section of code only.
- Using `split` to create an array named `alphabets` where all small letters alphabets are stored in it with index of `1,2,3`.. and so on.
- Now running for loop from 1 to till length of array alphabets.
- Now here print command will actually print all the commands(how they should actually run), but this will do only printing of them.
- Closing `awk` command and passing its output to `bash` will execute the commands and show the output on terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you find youself considering using awk like a shell (i.e. as a tool to call other tools from) you really need to think hard about whether or not it's the right approach.

Using any awk in any shell without the complications of having shell call awk to spawn a subshell to call date and then have getline try to read it and close the pipe, etc. as happens if you try to call date from awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for (i=0; i<=25; i++) print c=sprintf("%c",i+97), toupper(c)}' |
    while read c C; do date "+$c %$c | $C %$C"; done
a Tue | A Tuesday
b Apr | B April
c Tue Apr 14 09:03:28 2020 | C 20
d 14 | D 04/14/20
e 14 | E E
f f | F 2020-04-14
g 20 | G 2020
h Apr | H 09
i i | I 09
j 105 | J J
k  9 | K K
l  9 | L L
m 04 | M 03
n
 | N N
o o | O O
p AM | P P
q q | Q Q
r 09:03:28 AM | R 09:03
s 1586873008 | S 28
t    | T 09:03:28
u 2 | U 15
v 14-Apr-2020 | V 16
w 2 | W 15
x 04/14/2020 | X 09:03:28
y 20 | Y 2020
z -0500 | Z CDT
```

Comment: I have the same problem with `\n` and `\t` and my deleted answer.

Comment: @Cyrus I'm not sure that's a problem, it just is what it is...